# How do you take unspecified arithmetic claim (or another function) as parameter?

Tags: ocaml

For example,

(*) f is arithmetic claim: +, -, *, /. x is int list. y is int.

rawr applies f to each element of x with y and returns accumulated value *)

let rawr f x y= ....
....
....

rawr ( * ) [1;2;3] 2 should return (1*2) + (2*2) + (3*2) = 12

rawr (+) [1;2;3] 2 should return (1+2) + (2+2) + (3+2) = 12

I don't need to code rawr (this is just a random example I came up with to make my question clear), but I do need to take other function or arithmetic claims as a parameter (especially for rec or folding structures). I've been trying different formats but no success so far... can anyone please show how I can take unspecified arithmetic claim or function as parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to take a symbolic formula or an OCaml function, or whether you need to be able to accept either of these.

Let's assume you're happy with just a function parameter.

Functions as parameters to functions is something FP languages like OCaml do without breaking a sweat.

A canonical example of this is the function `List.fold_left`. Here's an implementation of `List.fold_left` that might show you what this kind of thing looks like:

```
let rec fold_left f accu l =
  match l with
    [] -> accu
  | a::l -> fold_left f (f accu a) l
```

If you use the parameter like a function, OCaml will figure out that it's a function. That's how type inference works.

You can use this function to add up a list of numbers:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let rec fold_left f accu l =
  match l with
    [] -> accu
  | a::l -> fold_left f (f accu a) l
        ;;
val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
# fold_left (+) 0 [4;5;7];;
- : int = 16
#
```

If, in fact, you want to accept *either* a function or some kind of symbolic expression, you need to figure out how to represent and evaluate your symbolic expressions. This doesn't come for free in OCaml, you'd have to define it.